# Starting new role, another manager wants to control part of my role

Tags: politics, team-role

I am starting a new role, where I will cover multiple functions.
Another manager just got promoted (just after three months, they might have had plans since his hiring) and changed his title to add one of the functions I'll cover.

I am happy and excited about my new role, but I am afraid of investing into something (that specific function, 30% of my time) that will lead nowhere, as it will be taken away from me: nobody is going to give me a promotion for a function which got moved outside my new team.

I am aware that this is a broader problem which primarily involves my manager, but I am interested in career advancement and I don't want to invest in a role which might get maimed soon.
Should I maintain my awareness of the situation, or trust my manager to solve this and completely ignore this possibility until the time comes?

Comment: Why would it get maimed just because a manager has it on their job description?

Comment: Coudn't you just ask YOUR manager how your responsibilities in the shared function differs from the OTHER manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking at this all wrong.. if career advancement is what drives you this is an *opportunity* not a problem. In simplistic terms you now have twice as many managers that you can impress (and have saying good things about you if you do), you have an opportunity to show you can manage multiple disparate responsibilities etc.

If you were a senior manager looking to promote somebody who would you be more likely to promote

a) the worker who neglected 30% of their job role because they thought it was a dead end

or

b) the worker who excelled in two different areas of the business